# Pandas DataFrame string replace followed by split and set intersection

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have following `pandas` `DataFrame`

```
data = ['18#38#123#23=>21', '18#38#23#55=>35']
d = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['rule'])
```

and I have list of integers

```
r = [18, 55]
```

and I want to filter rules from above `DataFrame` if all integers in the list `r` are present in the rule too. I tried the following code and failed

```
d[d['rule'].str.replace('=>','#').split('#').astype(set).issuperset(set(r))]
```

How can I achieve the desired filtering with `pandas`

Answer (score 2):

You were going in right direction, just need to use `apply` function instead:

`d[d['rule'].str.replace('=>','#').str.split('#').apply(lambda x: set(x).issuperset(set(map(str,r))))]`

Answer (score 1):

My initial instinct would be to use a `list` comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['18#38#123#23=>21', '188#38#123#23=>21', '#18#38#23#55=>35'], columns = ['rule'])

def wrap(n):
    return r'(?<=[^|^\d]){}(?=[^\d])'.format(n)

patterns = [18, 55]
pd.concat([df['rule'].str.contains(wrap(pattern)) for pattern in patterns], axis=1).all(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
```

Comment: Your solution might not exactly answer OP's problem. It gives the same output for `data = ['18#38#123#23=>21', '188#38#23#55=>35']`, while the expected output would be `False, False`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.get_dummies`

```
d.rule.str.replace('=>','#').str.get_dummies(sep='#').loc[:, map(str, r)].all(1)
```

Outputs

```
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool
```

---

Detail:

`get_dummies`+`loc` returns

```
    18  55
0   1   0
1   1   1
```

Comment: how can I use boolean indexes returned by your method to set the value of a new column in the dataframe?

Answer (score -1):

My approach is similar to @RafaelC's answer, but convert all `string` into `int`:

```
new_df = d.rule.str.replace('=>','#').str.get_dummies(sep='#')
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.astype(int)
has_all = new_df[r].all(1)

# then you can assign new column for initial data frame
d['new_col'] = 10
d.loc[has_all, 'new_col'] = 100
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------------------+------------+
|       |    rule           |   new_col  |
+-------+-------------------+------------+
|    0  | 18#38#123#23=>21  |      10    |
|    1  | 188#38#23#55=>35  |      10    |
|    2  | 18#38#23#55=>35   |     100    |
+-------+-------------------+------------+
```